# How to get the like between two arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

How to get the difference between two arrays in Javascript
likeArray([1, 2, 3, 7], [3, 2, 1, 4, 5]);//[1,2,3]

Comment: What do you mean by the difference? The difference of the sums of the numbers? Please provide more information.

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

There is a little function that compares 2 arrays and get the difference. The first parameter is you array and the second the one you want to compare to

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 7]
var array2 = [3, 2, 1, 4, 5]

Diff = function(a, d){
  return a.filter(_=>d.indexOf(_)<0)
}

console.log(Diff(array1, array2))

console.log(Diff(array2, array1))
```

Answer (score -1):

Pretty easy if you're supporting "newer" browsers.

```
    Array.prototype.diff = function (x) {
    return this.filter(function (y) {
        return a.indexOf(i) === -1;
    });
};
```

then you can call it like

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].diff([2, 4, 6]);`

Comment: diff is not a function

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz Yes I goofed with hitting send too early, deleted it right away and fixed it. Sorry for that mistake.